# Why can’t SBT resolve SecureSocial-snapshot dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use this SecureSocial snapshot for my project:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/

However SBT is unable to resolve it. Here is the error message:

```
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-master-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-master-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/ws.securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/ws/securesocial/securesocial_2.11/master-SNAPSHOT/securesocial_2.11-master-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.11;master-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Here are my resolvers and library dependencies:

Build.scala:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-3",
  "org.logback-extensions" % "logback-ext-loggly" % "0.1.2",
  "ws.securesocial" % "securesocial_2.11" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

As far as I can tell this should work, but it doesn’t. What is the cause of this problem?

Versions info:

- Scala version: 2.11.5
- SBT version: 0.13.8
- Play version: 2.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolvers that you add for libraries should go in the `build.sbt`, not in the `plugins.sbt`. These two files are not cascaded and if you see the output from sbt it is not even trying to connect to Sonatype. Move this line in the `build.sbt` and it should work:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

It is worth noting that you need to add resolvers in the `plugins.sbt` only when you want to include an sbt plugin that is not in the default repos.